# icefaces 3.3 rendered attribute does not work correct

Tags: java, jsf-2, icefaces, jsf-2.2, icefaces-3

I am using the rendered attritube to display a "x" in my datatable. The x is printed every time even if its value is false.

```
                <ace:column id="aktiviert" headerText="Aktiviert" sortBy="#{user.aktiviert}" filterBy="#{user.aktiviert}">
                    <ace:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="x" rendered="#{user.aktiviert}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <ace:checkboxButton id="aktiviertInput" value="#{user.aktiviert}" />                    
                        </f:facet>
                    </ace:cellEditor>      
                </ace:column>
```

If I put another outputText before, it works!

```
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="" rendered="#{user.aktiviert}"/>
                            <h:outputText value="x" rendered="#{user.aktiviert}"/>
                        </f:facet>
```

Now the x is only printed, if the boolean value at the backend is true. With the first access, my rendered attribute always works like the value is true.

Is there a known bug? This is since the update from icefaces 3.2 to 3.3.

This is my getter on the Entity.

```
@Column(name = "AKTIVIERT")
public Boolean getAktiviert() {
    System.out.println("Aktiviert : " + aktiviert);
    if (aktiviert == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return aktiviert;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are changing the properties via ajax, you will need to use the "alwaysExecuteContents" on the ace:dataTable.  I did a quick test and found once setting this attribute to "true", the rendered flag on the facets were updated properly.

Comment: thanks. but i am not changing any values with ajax. the rendering is going wrong at the initial load of the jsf site. alwaysExecuteContents did not work. my other columns are printed correctly. just the rendered attribute on a h:outputtext does not work on the first access.